# How to specify / fix default save location in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, filesystem

Every time I go to save (in Ubuntu 18.04) in Firefox, the default save location is something like: `run/user/1001/doc/f6f59daa`. So I have to manually click on my home directory or other folder on the left each time I want to save a file.

What I'm expecting inside is for the last used location to be the default, or failing that perhaps a specified downloads folder.

Why am I seeing this strange default path and how can I fix it?

Comment: How did you install Firefox?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Nmath I installed firefox via snap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Firefox Settings/General/Files and Applications, and set your default folder there.

[image]

**Update #1:**

Remove the SNAP version of Firefox and install the APT version.

`sudo snap remove firefox`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install firefox`

Comment: Hi, yes, this is a way to choose a default directory to save to. What I am asking is instead: why am I seeing this strange default path? If I want to choose the directory to save to, why does it always default there rather than the last directory (which would be my preference)?

Comment: @quiltedcomputer See Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: @quiltedcomputer Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Update #1 will be outdated within a few months with Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @vanadium That **may** be true. I hope they fix the 1) theme problem, and 2) the extensions management problem, and whatever else the SNAP has problems with. Grrr.

Comment: Thanks. Removing the snap and installing via apt solved it. Appreciated. Still wondering why the snap doesn't work this way.

Comment: @quiltedcomputer This is because SNAP apps are "sandboxed" to protect the system from apps that may try and do bad stuff... like ransomware, etc.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. and i learned more about the /run filesystem here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13972/what-is-this-new-run-filesystem